# Exe files show the default icon on the desktop, quick launch and in the start menu

Tags: windows-xp, windows-explorer, desktop

Is there any way to fix this?
It appears that the user ran some kind of registry cleaner after getting an error.

Editing the properties to point directly to a resource in the exe file does not work.
The exe file association is not missing and is correct.  The only thing I can think of is some Explorer Shell Extension/COM object was removed or unregistered yet I cannot figure out which one.  Any and all help appreciated.

Rebuilding the Icon cache and using Tweak UI did not help.

Comment: Did you try to reinstall (recover) Windows?

Comment: No! :) - I don't have a day to reinstall all the software.  A repair or recovery install would kill several apps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try resetting the icon cache

http://smallvoid.com/article/windows-icon-cache.html

Most registry cleaners back up the items they clean up, you might be able to restore them using the same program.

TweakUi from Microsoft also has a icon rebuild ability.

Main page
http://www.microsoft.com/windowsxp/downloads/powertoys/xppowertoys.mspx

Direct download
http://download.microsoft.com/download/f/c/a/fca6767b-9ed9-45a6-b352-839afb2a2679/TweakUiPowertoySetup.exe

After install of TweakUI click Start button/All Programs/Accessories/Powertoys

When TweakUI for Windows XP opens, in the left pane you'll see Repair, click that item, then in the right pane you'll see Rebuild Icons, click the Repair Now button.

EDIT:

If all else fails try a Microsoft System Restore, pick a date before the registry cleaner was used

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306084

.

.

Comment: Thanks for the advice Moab, but it did not work.

Comment: I hate registry cleaners, did you check to see if it made a backup?

Comment: No backup :(  It was like pulling teeth to get the user to admit what he did.  I'm thinking he deleted any backups etc to hide tracks.

Comment: Check my edit above.

Comment: System restore worked, but... It's a big hammer for a finishing nail.  I'm still curious what shell extensions are required to show icons from an exe file.  Guess I'll ask on stackoverflow :).  Thanks.